# Trouble getting value of element in Inspect.exe

Tags: c#, inspect, winium

I have to automate an application that currently uses RSA SecurID to get a passcode.

I'm able to open up the app, enter in my PIN, and click the button to show the passcode but once I get here I'm having trouble retrieving it.

Here is the Inspect.exe for the RSA app while it's currently showing a passcode that I want to retrieve:

[image]

Here are the specific details for the **Current code is** section:

[image]

I'm having trouble building out an Xpath that will retrieve just the passcode. I'm trying not to use the **Name** attribute because it contains the passcode and I won't know what it is until it gets generated so I am wanting to retrieve the value attribute because it is just the passcode:

[image]

So far, all the xpaths I've been trying have been returning null.

Comment: so you want to capture which value - 2052** or 4054** ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't super clear with my screenshots. Both of those numbers are essentially the same thing. The RSA passcode changes once a minute and I wasn't fast enough when taking screenshots and adding text :) I'd preferably like to get the Value attribute which will then return to me whatever 8 digit number is assigned to it.

Comment: Thats okay :).. This RSA App -are you using it on your browser or using it as a tool bar. I mean how are you accessing it. The reason I am asking is because we have got a RSA security token class in .net

Comment: The project team is using the RSA SecurID windows desktop app to enter in their PIN and then retrieve the passcode.

Comment: @Prany I actually figured out my issue. For some reason having the inspect.exe open was causing all kinds of issues while looking for an xpath. As soon as I closed it and started debugging I was able to start getting the results I expected.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason having the inspect.exe open was causing all kinds of issues while looking for an xpath. As soon as I closed it and started debugging I was able to start getting the results I expected.